# How can I send strings from an online HTML page list to a Java array?

Tags: java, html, arrays

I am new to Java. Currently I have an array with a lot of values that I copied manually from a html page.
These values are just a list of names that I lookup with a search filter that come up from a html page that is constantly updated.
I need help finding a way to maintain it so that my application connects to the html page through a GET request, and fetches these values automatically populating the array (preferably storing the big array in a separate file) rather than me updating it every time.

So let's say this is the list in the HTML page when I look up Italian food in search box:

- Pizza
- Pasta
- Ravioli
- etc ...

and my array is
`String[] foodNames = {"Pizza", "Pasta", "Ravioli" ...}`

Not that it's relevant, but I attached my code for a bit of context, it will not work for you as the cookie values and website are dummy values.
I hope my explanation made sense.
Thanks in advance!

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        //String to store all food names
        String[] foodNames = {"Pizza", "Pasta", "Ravioli" ...};

        //Webpage cookie to connect to webpage that requires login
        String cookie ="12345678912345678";


        for(String foodName : foodNames){
            System.out.println("-------------------" + foodName + "--------------------");
            //Get url
            URL foodRecipeUrl = new URL("https://horriblefoodrecipeslol.com/italian" + foodNames + "/+/ingredients/calories" );
            //Send request
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) foodRecipeUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            try {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            
            //Filter out special characters
            String plainText = result.toString().replaceAll("(?s)<[^>]*>(\\s*<[^>]*>)*", "");


            if(plainText.contains("pesto")){
                System.out.print("This recipe is Italian");
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println(String.format("No food for you", foodName));
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the page static or is there some JavaScript code which adds content after the initial page is loaded?

Comment: @Eritrean Yeah it's basically just a website constantly updated by other people, and I am trying to get values from the page when I look up with search filter e.g. "recipes"

Comment: Then you may take a look at [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) a HTML parser which you can use to extract the data you need from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a simple example using Jsoup to get you started for the following website:
https://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/category/world/italian/

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TestJsoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String html = "https://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/category/world/italian/";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
        Elements recipeTitles = doc.select("div.recipe-title");
        for(Element e : recipeTitles){
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Super-quick fresh pasta
Buddy's Bolognese
Beautiful courgette carbonara
Broccoli & anchovy orecchiette
Spaghetti with anchovies, dried chilli & pangrattato
Epic vegan lasagne
Danny Devito's family pasta
Amazing ravioli
Rolled cassata
Amalfi lemon tart
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a library called jsonsimple however your suggestion was very helpful in pointing me in the right direction.